# How can I take out a value as a string from RealmSwift?

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I am developing an iOS app with RealmSwift by referring here. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#in-memory-realms
And, what I don't understand is, how can I indicate the location(record and column) of the data in the realm file.

I've saved a realm file that named "DicData.realm" on the main folder where the same location as ViewController.swift is saved.

The data of DicData.realm is something like this:

```
1,face,423
2,rain,435
3,airplane,555
```

If I run the code below, it only printed like this: "results: Results (  )". It seems the filter method is just neglected. When I want to take out the word "airplane" and store in a variable as a string, how should I modify my code?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    func test()->Int {
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "DicData"))
    let results = realm.objects(DBData).filter("id == 3")

    print("results: \(results)")        
}

class DBData: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var code = ""
}
```

Comment: try `let results = realm.objects(DBData).filter($0.id == 3)` instead

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It fails with "anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure" error.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the closure. Here's the updated line: `let results = realm.objects(DBData).filter({ $0.id == 3 })`

Comment: Thanks again, but this code only prints "results: []".

Comment: Sorry I was bit wrong. When I run my first code "let results = realm.objects(DBData).filter("id == 3")", I got following result; "results: Results<CSVData> ()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring here to the chapter of **in-memory Realms** and have setup your configuration to use those. An **in-memory Realm** is not a file. It lives exclusively in memory and is not actually written to disk.

If you've a prepared file, you want to bundle with your app, you need to make sure, that it is part of the **Copy-Files Build Phase** of the corresponding target of your Xcode project.

You can then copy the file from the app bundle initially via `NSFileManager` to a path, where the copy can be modified.

```
let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DicData", withExtension: "realm")!
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: defaultURL)
} catch {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I've replaced "v0URL" with bundleURL, and ran your code but it (the 2nd line) failed with the following error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Fixed the wrong variable name in the code above. Have you made sure that the file is copied into the app bundle?

Comment: I don't think the file is copied properly. When I bundled a file named "DicData.csv" in the same location, and modified the second line into "let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DicData", withExtension: "csv")!", I don't get any error, but just got the error message that I wrote inside of catch{}.